# Linux Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, file, terminal, segmentation-fault

I need to simulate the effect of the grep -f command between 2 files
The code gets compiled with no errors, but when I run it instead of the output it displays Segmentation fault (core dumped)
How can I that? Also if you can help with a better way to open f1 and f2 without using aux1 and aux2 to provide the name of the file that would be great. Thanks in advance.

//I know I have to check if the code has enough arguments and if not I should do something with stderr (that's I've been told to do in class but I don't know how)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *file1;
  FILE *file2;
  char aux1[100]="",aux2[100]="";
  strcpy(aux1,argv[1]);
  strcpy(aux2,argv[2]);
  file1 = fopen("aux1","r");
  file2 = fopen("aux2","r");

  char s1[100]="",s2[100]="";
  char aux[100]="";

  while(fscanf(file1,"%s",aux)!=EOF)
  {
    strcat(s1,aux);
    strcat(s1," ");
  }
  s1[strlen(s1)-1]='\0';

  while(fscanf(file2,"%s",aux)!=EOF)
  {
    strcat(s2,aux);
    strcat(s2," ");
  }
  s2[strlen(s2)-1]='\0';

  printf("%s\n",strstr(s2,s1));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 100 is certainly a big number, but are you sure it's big enough for all your strings?

Comment: Also, grep says that -f will "Obtain patterns from file, one per line", and I don't see you checking for line endings in either file.

Comment: This `while(fscanf(file1, "%s", aux) != EOF)` should be `while(fscanf(file1, "%99s", aux) == 1)` (two changes), other lines too.

Comment: When you get a core dump, you should look at it.  Sometimes, you will have some insight and realize what the issue is 10ms after you see that a core dump happened and you don't need to look at it.  If you don't get that insight, it takes about 3 seconds to open the core dump and get a backtrace which often shows you exactly where the problem is and then you get the necessary insight.  Understanding how to look at a core dump is a key skill that should be learned.

Comment: But in this case, you don't need to learn how to read a core dump; you need a basic primer on C.

Comment: re: opening the file without needing to copy the argument, I like using an auxiliary function like https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/0922b1fe14bace4dcf5e0f9d3ba5940abcf77dd4/c/lib/xutil.c#L9-L19 You can call it as in https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/0922b1fe14bace4dcf5e0f9d3ba5940abcf77dd4/c/main/read-txt-into-array.c#L31

Comment: Try to find a video tutorial teaching you how to use a debugger. This allows you to step through the code and inspect variables on the run. It should be easy to find the mistake doing that. Also, it often help to extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one big mistake:

```
strcpy(aux1, argv[1]); 
file1 = fopen("aux1", "r");
```

You aren't opening the file passed, and without checking whether it opened, you lurch right into a segfault by using a `NULL` file pointer.

It should be

```
file1 = fopen(aux1, "r");     // removed " marks
if(file1 == NULL)
    exit(1);
```

You also asked how to avoid using `aux1` which can be done with

```
if(argc < 2)
    exit(1);
fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  FILE *file1;
  FILE *file2;
  char aux1[100]="",aux2[100]="";
  strcpy(aux1,argv[1]);
  strcpy(aux2,argv[2]);
  file1 = fopen("aux1","r");
  file2 = fopen("aux2","r");
```

- You do not check if any command-line arguments were provided before copying them to `aux1` and `aux2`.
- You use `"aux1"` and `"aux2"` as the names of the files instead of the contents of `aux1` and `aux2`. You don't require the two variables, simply pass `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` to `fopen()` directly.
- You do not check if the calls to `fopen()` succeeded. `fopen()` returns `NULL` to indicate failure.

```
while(fscanf(file1,"%s",aux)!=EOF)
  {
    strcat(s1,aux);
    strcat(s1," ");
  }
```

- There is no check to see if this concatenation exceeds the length of `s1`, which is only large enough to hold 100 characters. You'd require dynamic allocation here.

```
printf("%s\n",strstr(s2,s1));
```

- `strstr()` returns `NULL` if the substring was not found. You do not check its return value before passing it to `printf()`.

> I know I have to check if the code has enough arguments and if not I
> should do something with stderr (that's I've been told to do in class
> but I don't know how)

Simply check the value of `argc` (argument count):

```
/* Change 3 according to your requirements. */
if (argc != 3) {
   fputs( /* Error message here. */, stderr); 
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```